# Supplementary notes to Mumford's The Red Book of Varieties and Schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am a graduate student with good mathematical maturity (I took advanced courses like category theory, commutative algebra...). I want to study algebraic geometry from Mumford's red book. I find it difficult to keep motivated. Is there any class notes supplements Mumford?

Comment: Maybe you would find some more examples motivating, such as are found in Harris's introductory book Algebraic Geometry, or Igor Dolghachev's free book on classical algebraic geometry, available on his website: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/CAG.pdf Fulton's Algebraic Curves is also free now I think, http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf  and there is the fascinating old book by Semple and Roth.

Comment: [PDF]Solutions to Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry - WordPress ...
https://divisibility.files.wordpress.com/2013/.../fullhartshornesolutions1.p...
Solutions to Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry. Andrew Egbert. October 3, 2013.

Comment: Hartshorne'book is an excellent classical graduate ref. in Algebraic Geometry. It is not free but it contains plenty of exercises the solutions of which are free ! (see above).

Comment: I’m in a (¿similar?) position. I find Miles Reid’s stuff more concrete (UAG, OPV, Fano 3-folds, …). I also liked Knörrer and Brieskorn’s book which begins with a lot of actual drawings (with history!) of specific curves.

If you look at Stillwell, Brieskorn, Hirzebruch, Reid, you will see overlaps. The Simons Foundation interviewed Brieskorn; this video could be a start.

Fulton helps too. Plus _3264 and all that_. I’m someone for whom consulting 3–10 sources in parallel is somehow easier than 1 (like balancing a stool on one leg).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could have a look at Vakil's "Foundations of algebraic geometry" ? [Available on his Stanford homepage]

Eisenbud&Harris' "Geometry of schemes" is quite good to get the points too (pun intended)

Comment: Vakil is great, but definitely need presence of motivation.

Comment: Learning anything seriously needs presence and motivation! The only thing you can gain by acting like a vegetable is weight :-P