# A few general questions about pre-sheaves and sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory

I am no specialist in sheaf theory, so I would be glad to get some help regarding the following:

I have a pre-sheaf $F$ of abelian groups above a topological space $X$, and I have found an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ such that, for any $i$, $F(U_i)$ is a direct sum: $$F(U_i) = \underset{l}{\bigoplus} F^l (U_i),$$ where $F^l$ are pre-sheaves on $X$.

I have the two following questions:

1. Is it true in general that a direct sum of pre-sheaves (resp. sheaves) of abelian groups is a pre-sheaf (resp. sheaf), or does it have to be a finite sum ? If it is true, how do we define sections and restriction morphisms for general direct sums of pre-sheaves ?
2. How to prove that the sheafification $F^{\#}$ of $F$ is given by the direct sum: $$F^{\#} = \underset{l}{\bigoplus} F^{l \#},$$ where $F^{l \#}$ is the sheafification of $F^l$ ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: For the second question, there is a very easy answer with abstract nonsense: as a coproduct of presheaves is a colimit, it is preserved by any left-adjoint functor. In particular, sheafification, being left adjoint to the inclusion Sheaves $\to$ Presheaves, preserves a coproduct

Answer (score 2):

The answer to 1 was too long as a comment, so I will write it here.

Regarding 1, the answer is 'yes', meaning that one can define the notion of a direct sum of presheaves of abelian groups, but please check the details.

Suppose we have presheaves $F^l$ of abelian groups on a topological space $X$. We want to define their direct sum

$F = \bigoplus_l F^l$

First, we define, for $U$ an open subset of $X$,

$F(U) = \bigoplus_l F^l(U)$ .

Moreover, if $V \subseteq U$ is an open subset of $X$ contained in $U$, we denote the restriction homomorphisms of $F^l$ by $h^l_{VU}$, so that

$h^l_{VU}: F^l(U) \to F^l(V)$ .

We now define the restriction homomorphism $h_{VU}: F(U) \to F(V)$ as follows. Let $i_k(W): F^k(W) \to \bigoplus_l F^l(W)$ be the natural homomorphisms, where $W$ is an arbitrary open subset of $X$.

Consider the homomorphisms $g^l_{VU} = i_l(V) \circ h^l_{VU}: F^l(U) \to F(V)$. By the universal property of coproducts, satisfied by direct sums of abelian groups, there is a unique homomorphism $h_{VU}: F(U) \to F(V)$ such that $g^l_{VU} = h_{VU} \circ i_l(U)$ for any $l$.

Thus we have defined restriction homomorphisms $h_{VU}$, and it remains to check that they satisfy the required properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check the properties.
Do you have an idea for the second question ?

Answer (score 2):

This is an "abstract nonsense" answer. If you're not familiar with a bit of category theory this will probably be useless.

For the second question :

Denote by $L$ the sheafification functor $\mathbf{Psh}(X) \to \mathbf{Sh}(X)$.

By definition (or construction,...) $L$ is left adjoint to the inclusion $i: \mathbf{Sh}(X) \to \mathbf{Psh}(X)$; hence it preserves colimits.

Now let $(F^l)_l$ be a family of presheaves, $\displaystyle\bigoplus_lF^l$ can be defined as in Malkoun's answer and is actually the coproduct of the $F^l$'s in $\mathbf{Psh}(X)$; hence $L(\displaystyle\bigoplus_lF^l) = \displaystyle\bigoplus_lL(F^l)$ which is exactly what you wanted.

Edit : there's a mistake in what comes right above : $L$ does preserve colimits, but the inclusion functor need not do so as well; hence the second $\bigoplus$ is *not* the direct sum in $\mathbf{Psh}(X)$, it is the direct sum in $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$; which can be defined using $L$. Hence the answer to your question is "yes if the second $\bigoplus$ is taken in $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$ and not in $\mathbf{Psh}(X)$.". In particular, taking sections over $U$ need not be the sum of the sections.

By the way you can answer the first question in the same way: $\mathbf{Ab}$ is an abelian cocomplete category, hence $\mathbf{Psh}(X)$ is also abelian cocomplete; and also for any open set $U\subset X$, the "evaluation at $U$" functor preserves colimits, hence $(\displaystyle\bigoplus_lF^l)(U)$ is $\displaystyle\bigoplus_lF^l(U)$. Restriction morphisms come from the universal property of the coproduct, as described in Makoun's answer ($\displaystyle\bigoplus_l$ can in fact be seen as a functor $\mathbf{Ab}^I \to \mathbf{Ab}$ where $I$ is the set of indices for this very reason)

Comment: nice. I need to learn more catergory theory, it helps make the arguments cleaner. My answer for question 2 was a bit clumsy. I am glad you confirmed, via a more "high-tech" point of view.

Comment: @Malkoun : once the right notions are in place, you can let category theory guide you gently ;-) (for question 2.; neither argument I'm using is complicated once you know the definitions of the words used)

Comment: I guess part of me likes to keep things very concrete and as explicit as possible, but this makes what I write quite difficult to read, and I get bogged down in detail. I do appreciate though the power of looking at maps rather than objects, well exploited by Grothendieck. I do appreciate the power of abstract nonsense, but I tend not to think that way. Do you have any good reference for category theory for geometers, with an emphasis on its connections with algebraic geometry (as in "Categories for the Working Geometer"?).

Comment: @Malkoun unfortunately I don't personnally know any such references, but looking around a bit on MO gives the following questions (and answers !) : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/216215/category-theory-for-algebraic-geometry and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212548/supplementary-notes-to-mumfords-the-red-book-of-varieties-and-schemes/212551#212551

Comment: Thanks a lot Max and Malkoun, I’ll try to learn the basics to understand your argument which seems to be almost straightforward as soon as you know the definitions and concepts.

Comment: Last question, is it possible tu apply the same argument to show that a direct sum of sheaves is a sheaf ?

Comment: There is also one last thing: I said in my question that the pre-sheaf was a direct sum a priori only on a fixed open cover (which is not necessarily a basis of topology). How do I get the result for the sheafifications on any open sets ?

Comment: To answer your last question : indeed my answer doesn't take that into question (I was thinking it was a different question, i.e. in general is the sheafification of a direct sum the direct sum of sheafifications ). In your general situation where you compare two presheaves on some open cover, I don't know that much can be said...  Suppose for instance $I$ has one element and $U_i =X$ and suppose there are no nontrivial global sections; then you can't say anything about the sheafification ..

Comment: @Malkoun : your last statement is not correct ! Consider the example I gave just above; where $F(X) = F(X)\oplus F(X)$ but $F$ need not be isomorphic to $F\oplus F$

Comment: I deleted my last two comments. I am tired, so forgive me for my "concrete nonsense".

Comment: @Malkoun : your second-to-last comment was however relevant ! Consider indeed a direct sum of sheaves $F=\bigoplus_l F^l$. Then its sheafification is $\bigoplus_l L(F^l)\simeq \bigoplus F^l$ (the $F^l$ are sheaves) and so it's $F$ : $F$ is a sheaf.

Comment: @Max, I see. Thank you for explaining this carefully. I have also learned today about the "co-continuity of left-adjoint functors". I have not seen the proof, but it should not be too difficult, I hope. Nice discussion BrianT and Max.

Comment: @Max : I may be tired too, so correct me if I’m wrong. I think that in order to answer my last question, one needs to be able to do the following : given the restriction of a presheaf to an open cover, sheafifising this restriction to get a sheaf on this open cover; then recovering the whole sheaf by extending (somehow) to any open set, and finally prove that the sheaf so obtained is the sheafification of the original presheaf. Do you think this is possible ?

Comment: Would it help if the open cover was a basis for the topology of X ?

Comment: We need to fix this discussion! The direct sum of sheaves, as a presheaf, is not a sheaf in general. There are some posts such as this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193816/direct-and-inverse-limits-of-sheaves, which contain counterexamples.

Comment: That’s weird. It seemed that the argument above was correct. Also, I really need to understand this this about open covers...

Comment: @Malkoun : I am so sorry; I made a huge mistake... Indeed; let me edit my answer and try to answer all the last points made here

Comment: BrianT : you cannot sheafify a "restriction to an open cover". Sheafifying $F$ uses the whole $F$. I gave you the example where the open cover is $X$ for instance and there are no global sections : you cannot recover $F$ from that.

Comment: Max : thanks for your answer. Does this help if the open cover is a basis for the topology ? Also, could I didn’t understand very well your edit. Could you explain it ? Thanks a lot again

Comment: Well you can't recover $F$ from its values on a basis because $F$ is only a presheaf (if it were a sheaf, we could recover its values from those on a basis); and I think (here I'm not so sure but almost) that we cannot recover the sheafification either. For my edit, the point is that coproducts in the category $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$ might look very different from those in $\mathbf{Psh}(X)$. In the latter (which is just a functor category) colimits (in particular coproducts) are computed pointwise, that is here $(\bigoplus_l F^l)(U) = \bigoplus_l F^l(U)$ (cont)

Comment: (cont) But that's not the case in $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$: the previous formula does not hold. *However*, there is still a notion of coproduct in $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$, and sheafification transforms the previous "naive" coproduct in $\mathbf{Psh}(X)$ into the "weird" coproduct in $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$: one needs to be careful with what $\bigoplus$ means. In other words, the coproduct of sheaves,as computed in $\mathbf{Psh}(X)$, that is, pointwise, is not the coproduct of sheaves as computed in $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$ (for this to make sense you have to know what "coproduct" means in a category)

Comment: Max: ok, thanks a lot, it’s clearer now. About the open cover thing, suppose that the open cover is a basis, and that we know what the presheaf looks like above this basis. Can’t we sheafifise « above the basis » to get a B-sheaf (I think this is the terminology for sheaves over a basis), and then reconstruct the whole sheafification of the original sheaf from it ?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your last question. I would say "no", because as I said the data of a presheaf on a basis is not enough to recover the presheaf, and probably not enough to recover the sheafification of the presheaf. What you can do is define a certain sheaf $G$ from the values $F(U_i)$, but if $F$ is bad enough, $G$ and $F$ won't even coincide on the $U_i$'s (going from a B-sheaf to a sheaf uses the gluing axiom in an essential manner)

Comment: I don’t understand where the problem is with what you said. If we construct the sheaf $G$ from the B-sheaf obtained via the data $F(U_i)$, then $G$ need not coincide with $F$ on $U_i$, but with the sheafification of $F$. I may be totally confused, but isn’t it what it should be (the original claim was: take the restriction of a presheaf to a basis, and construct a B-sheaf; then the sheaf obtained from this B-sheaf is the sheafification of the presheaf) ?

Comment: But the $F(U_i)$ do not form a  B-sheaf; so who knows what $G$ might look like ? It need not be a sheaf at all, so you still have to sheafify it; and I don't think that its sheafification will look like $F$'s.

Comment: But can’t we construct a B-sheaf from the data $F(U_i)$, and then define $G$ as the sheaf associated to this B-sheaf ?

Comment: I don't see how to get a B-sheaf from the $F(U_i)$ without constructing a presheaf then sheafifying it to finally take the B-restriction. But again, I'm not sure

Comment: Max, I guess the statement you are making, namely that the direct sum of the sheafifications is the sheafification of the direct sum, but with the direct sum notion being taken in the corresponding category (presheaves/sheaves) could be confusing. In some sense, it can be taken as the definition of direct sums in the category of sheaves. So it can be viewed as a definition.

Comment: I don't know. I wish we could clean up this page, and remove many of the comments (including mine of course), to make it more readable.

Comment: @Malkoun you are right. I'll try to edit my answer in a reasonable way

Comment: In any case, I’m happy my question has raised such an interesting discussion. Actually, I asked that because I’m trying to understand a result from a paper in which one computes the cohomology of a sheaf (actually a presheaf) knowing that, on a certain open cover, the presheaf looks like a direct sum of presheaves which are $\mathbb{C}$ or $0$ depending on the open set. The result should be that the cohomology is the direct sum of the cohomology of the “constant or 0” sheaves. If it interests someone I can ask this more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

I am just adding a tiny bit that is missed from the previous 2 answers, that is, the resp. part of Question 1:

> If $F^l$ are sheaves on $X$, is $\oplus_l F^l$, which exists in the category of presheaves on $X$, automatically a sheaf on $X$?

The answer is **NO**. For a counterexample see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498298/products-and-sums-of-sheaves).

Comment: Hi. I followed the link, but could not find the counterexample. Do you mean in Ravi Vakil's notes?

Comment: Hi Fan Zheng, so can you tell me where the above argument of Max fails : let $F^l$ be sheaves, and $F$ be the functor sheafification. Then $$F(\underset{l}{\bigoplus} F^l) = \underset{l}{\bigoplus} F(F^l) = \underset{l}{\bigoplus} F^l$$

Comment: I did some search, and indeed, some counterexamples can be found for example here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193816/direct-and-inverse-limits-of-sheaves

Comment: @BrianT Sheafification doesn't commute with direct sum as the definition of sheafification involves products, possibly infinite, and infinite products don't commute with infinite sums.

Comment: @WillSawin probably the actual reason is that in my "proof" the second $\bigoplus$ is the direct sum *in $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$* (I realized my blunder too late) and this does *not* coincide with the direct sum in $\mathbf{Psh}(X)$ (the inclusion functor does not commute with direct sums, while the sheafification functor does)

Comment: @Max I was referring to the sheafificatiin functor  from presheaves to presheaves . It's all the same.

Comment: @WillSawin ah ok seeing $L:\mathbf{Psh}(X) \to \mathbf{Psh}(X)$. Since this is a tiny bit subtle it's good to make it clear haha

Comment: I think this page needs some cleaning up.

Comment: @Malkoun: A HUGE Sorry. What happened is that I opened too many mathoverflow tags and copied the wrong address. LInk has been fixed.